# TypeError: fetch failed - RequestContentLengthMismatchError in Next.js API endpoint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm encountering an issue with a Next.js API endpoint where I'm getting a TypeError: fetch failed error with a RequestContentLengthMismatchError. This issue occurs when I try to make a request to the endpoint using Postman.

```js
// pages/api/user/forms2.ts

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<{ [key: string]: string }[]>
) {
    return res.status(200).json([])
}
```

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (/Users/janoskukoda/Workspace/tikex/team/tikex-portal/lib/internal/deps/undici/undici.js:11730:11)
    at async invokeRequest (/Users/janoskukoda/Workspace/tikex/team/tikex-portal/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/server-ipc/invoke-request.js:17:12)
    // ... (additional stack trace)
    RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header
    // ...
```

1. Sart the Next.js development server.
2. Access the API endpoint at http://localhost:3000/api/user/forms2.
3. Observe the error in the console.